# Getting error value of type 'any' has no member 'value'

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Learning Swift and created a app where there is just a label and a slider. I want the slider to change the label as it slides.

Here is the func :

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        label.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    }
```

Im getting the error "value of type 'any' has no member 'value' " and if i correct it, it tries to correct the code to :

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        label.text = String(Int((sender as AnyObject).value))
    }
```

But still there is an error of

> Ambiguous use of 'value'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `sender` type any to `UISlider`.

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        label.text = String(Int(sender.value))
 }
```

Comment: No Problem. Glad to help you :)

Comment: Will set as answer as soon as i can !:)

Comment: Thanks @VanoshanRamdhani :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose to create IBAction:

[image: ibaction]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it in correct type.

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
   if let slider = sender as? UISlider {
       print(slider.value)
   }
}
```